# How to add quotation to strings in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I add quotation marks to where there's a text in a file  using notepad++ ?
Input :

```
1718;1070010;20240128;1;
000005002;000000501;"";whatif;""; ;"";"";2024-01-2804:43:20;0;"";0;1;0;"";2024-12-31;"R2";"R3";Division;smou7ich@wanadoo.fr;0;0;"";0;"";0
000005003;000000501;"";what;""; ;"";"";2024-01-2804:43:20;0;"";0;1;0;"";2024-12-31;"R2";"R3";Division;smouxknxskl7ich@wanadoo.fr;0;0;"";0;"";0
```

output should be :

```
1718;1070010;20240128;1;
000005002;000000501;"";"whatif";""; ;"";"";2024-01-2804:43:20;0;"";0;1;0;"";2024-12-31;"R2";"R3";"Division";"smou7ich@wanadoo.fr";0;0;"";0;"";0
000005003;000000501;"";"what";""; ;"";"";2024-01-2804:43:20;0;"";0;1;0;"";2024-12-31;"R2";"R3";"Division";"smouxknxskl7ich@wanadoo.fr";0;0;"";0;"";0
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=;)(?:([-\d:\h]+)|([^"\r\n;]+))(?=;)`
- Replace with: `(?2"$2":$1)`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=;)          # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a semicolon before
(?:             # non capture group
    (               # group 1
        [-\d:\h]+       # character class, dash, digit, colon or horizontal space, 1 or more times
    )               # end group 1
  |               # OR
    (               # group 2
        [^"\r\n;]+      # any character that is not quote, line break or semicolon
    )               # end group 2
)               # end group
(?=;)           # positive lookahead, make sure we hace a semicolon after
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?2         # if group 2 exissts
    "$2"        # print it surrounded by quotes
  :           # else
    $1          # print group 1
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]